# How to achieve 0 training error when using one-hidden-layer neural network with random inputs?

Tags: neural-network, interpolation

In theory, one-hidden-layer neural network with **m** hidden nodes can be trained by gradient descent to fit **n** data points with 0 training error, where **m >= n**.

I have 100 data points (x, y), **x** in R and **y** in R, no specific pattern, just random. And I was using one-hidden-layer neural network with 1000/2000/10000/... hidden nodes to fit those points (with stochastic gradient descent and ReLU).

But I can't achieve that. Any idea what's the problem here?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import initializers

## initializing x_train and y_train randomly ##
def f1(x): 
    if x < 3:
        return np.abs(x-1)
    else:
        return -np.abs(x-1)+4

n = 100
x_train = np.random.uniform(-4+1, 4+1, size = n)
e = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, size = n)
y_train = np.vectorize(f1)(x_train) + e
np.random.shuffle(y_train)

k = 10000 # number of hidden nodes
ep = 5
loss = []
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(k, kernel_initializer = 'random_normal', input_shape = (1,), use_bias=True))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'random_normal', use_bias=True))
#sgd = SGD(lr=0.00005, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9)
sgd = SGD(lr=0.00008)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=sgd, metrics = ['mse'])

for i in range(5000):
    H = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=ep, verbose=False)
    wt = model.get_weights()
    temp = H.history['mean_squared_error'][-1]
    print(temp)
    loss.append(temp)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxWgQ.png)

Comment: Can't do much without your code

Comment: Thanks for replying. Just posted code.

Answer (score 0):

What is your loss function? Can you show your code and perhaps some printouts of the loss per training epoch? How are you initializing the parameters of those hidden nodes (also do the nnn/nnnn/nnnn in your description mean those are different experimental settings?)?

Comment: I used mean squared error loss function and random normal initialization. And yes they are different settings. Sorry about the lack of information!